# Valums-File-Uploader - Submit file using Java and Selenium

Tags: javascript, java, selenium-webdriver, valums-file-uploader

Im trying to submit a file to [Valums-File-Uploader](https://github.com/Valums-File-Uploader/file-uploader) but im having trouble getting the file to submit/upload action to start. Im able to send example.txt to the file input but I am unable to make the submit action take place. Does anyone know how I can do this?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that i wasnt using an absolute path which Valums-File-Uploader requires.

.sendKeys("C:\workspace\project\src\resources\data\ExampleCV.docx");

use double \